# Inspect Element on Windows Phone

Tags: webview, windows-phone

I am developing a mobile web page for several mobile OSes. On Android and iOS, it looks fine but on WindowsPhone, the alignment is a mess. On iOS, i can inspect element on the web view using Safari, but I wonder how to do this on Windows Phone. Is there any way to do this? I only have Mac OS 10.8.5 for development. Been searching without result. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Inspect Element is not available on Mobile IE.

The recommended way to test your site is via the desktop version of IE as it shares most of its codebase with Mobile IE.

You can use a VM if you are on MacOS (you can find the IE VMs here: http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools)

Windows Phone 7 runs IE9 and Windows Phone 8 runs IE10.

Comment: I see, so by inspecting element and fixing the page using IE10, we can assume that it will display correctly to on Windows Phone 8 Webview. Thanks, gonna try your suggestion!